# Tracking object that is missing in some frames

Tags: opencv, tracking

I am trying to track small object in videos using LK 
but the problem is, some time the object does not appear in the frames !

How can I track an object that does not appear in few frames ?? 
 how can I approximate it is place automatically ,,,

I am trying to find the object using Optical flow LK ... but this technique lost when my   object does not appear

Any suggestion ideas ???

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: use your optical flow algorithm to get the best-fit warping of some number of previous images into your current image.  Then assume that your object is moving on a line through the images, and do some kind of robust best-fit to that line.  When the object reappears it is more likely to be near the predicted projection of the line than not.

You didn't give enough specifics in your question to really say more than that.

I assume by "LK" you mean "[the Lucas-Kanade optical flow algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Kanade_method)?"  But what are you really doing?  Are you taking image pyramids of each image and then doing multiple iterations of warping at each level of the pyramid?  Are you really doing the simplest form of Lucas-Kanade or are you actually doing one of the varieties of [Kanade-Lucas-Tomasi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanade%E2%80%93Lucas%E2%80%93Tomasi_Feature_Tracker) where you are concentrating on "corners"?

What is your description of an "object"?  Is it really just a "feature" (a corner point) or a small set of features?

You may need to use a more accurate and robust optical flow algorithm.  For example, some variation that does dense estimation (rather than the sparse estimation done by Lucas-Kanade) and that uses more robust distance metrics than least squares.

For example:

[Secrets of optical flow estimation and their principles](http://cs.brown.edu/people/dqsun/pubs/cvpr_2010_flow.pdf)
Sun, D., Roth, S., and Black, M. J.,
IEEE Conf. on Computer Vision and Pattern Recog., CVPR, June 2010.

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for your replay ... Actually I am trying to find a small object in X-ray images which is epiglottis !!! ... I wanna track it is movement from videos of x-ray images.. I am taking input from the user which is the place of the tip of the epiglottis ... then I wanna find it in all other frames ... 
yes I am using Optical Flow LK as you said ... but this algorithm cannot find the object when it does not appear in some frames !!! ... Also I do not know how can I approximate the place ! ...

Comment: Epiglottis does not have any special feature !! ... not corner of edge or anything ... but optical flow find it in the first half of the movement because it is still appear ,,,

Comment: how can I approximate the place ? ... any help will b so appreciated :D

Comment: Now I'm confused.  How is LK "finding" the tip of the epiglottis in the frames where it is visible?  All LK tells you is what parts of the image are moving.

Comment: I give LK the location of the tip only to find it in next frame .... it is working with me but only when the tip is visible ....

Comment: is there other way to track it ... I need only track one location in the image

Comment: Ah, that's a completely different question.  You want an "epiglottis recognizer," I guess.  You should post a picture with an arrow pointing out what you want to identify.  Surely it must have some distinguishing feature (otherwise how are you identifying it in your first image?)  Also, are there any other constraints you can take advantage of?  Are the images always taken from about the same distance from the epiglottis?  Are there any other distinguishing features in the picture that don't move?

Comment: each frame has a lateral view for the patient while swallowing ... I can see the vertebrae , head , tooth ... and many other ... the epiglottis very small part in the image 
the data that I am working on similar to this video 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=umnnA50IDIY

Comment: Here is the image for the tip that I am trying to track
http://i.imgur.com/ak832Lc.png

Comment: So far in my project I am using other feature to find the epiglottis area ... like I am using the vertebrae to know where is the epiglottis ..... Now I need to find the tip exactly ... this tip moves like a fan from upward to downward then go back .... when this tip reach to its maximum place , it is attach with other thing ... then it is start to go back ,,,, due to this attaching LK lost the place !!!

Comment: Apply a Laplacian filter. It emphasizes corners. Applyling it to the image you sent the tip of the epiglottis isn't the most emphasized thing, but it should be good enough: http://i.imgur.com/WeDax6j.png

Comment: I did many experiments like this stuff ... I smooth the image then binarize it... also I try to do the histogram equalization ... the problem is when the tip missing in the frame ! ,,, I did not know how to approximate its place